# Constructor element is undefined and returns error

Tags: reactjs

Simple problem but I can't figure out the solution. I have a simple character counter on a textbox which works as expected, however, I'm having trouble with the `constructor` and `componentWillReceiveProps`. I get an error `.length undefined.`. How do I get this to work when length is undefined?

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const profileCandidateCollection = props.profileCandidate;
  const summary = profileCandidateCollection && profileCandidateCollection.summary;
  const count = 3000 - (profileCandidateCollection && profileCandidateCollection.summary.length);

  this.state = {
    count: count,
  };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  const profileCandidateCollection = nextProps.profileCandidate;
  const summary = profileCandidateCollection && profileCandidateCollection.summary;
  const count = 3000 - (profileCandidateCollection && profileCandidateCollection.summary.length);

  this.setState({
    count: count,
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet that reproduces the error?

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

The solution that appears to be working is using an if statement and dropping  `const` in favour of `var`. I'm not sure why that works.

```
if(summary == null) {
    var count = 0;
  } else {
    var count = 3000 - (profileCandidateCollection && profileCandidateCollection.summary.length);
  }

  this.setState({
    count: count
  });
  }
```